# Array search in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like below the page. I want to find array number which [itag] => 22 . 
In this example this is [1], means:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [url] => asd2
            [quality] => hd720
            [fallback_host] => ax2
            [type] => video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2\"
            [itag] => 22
        )
```

How could I find this in these array structure: ?

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => asd1
            [quality] => hd720
            [fallback_host] => ax1
            [type] => video/webm; codecs=\"vp8.0, vorbis\"
            [itag] => 45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => asd2
            [quality] => hd720
            [fallback_host] => ax2
            [type] => video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2\"
            [itag] => 22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => asd3
            [quality] => large
            [fallback_host] => ax3
            [type] => video/webm; codecs=\"vp8.0, vorbis\"
            [itag] => 44
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [url] => asd4
            [quality] => large
            [fallback_host] => ax4
            [type] => video/x-flv
            [itag] => 35
        )



)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a low-tech solution, without anything fancy:

```
$matchKey = null;
foreach($array as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['itag'] == 22) {
         $matchKey = $key;
         break;
    }
}

if($matchKey === null) {
    echo 'Not found.';
}
else {
    echo 'Key found: '.$matchKey;
}
```

Comment: PHP < 5.3 is like IE =( If you support it, you're holding back internet.

Answer (score 0):

array_filter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
<?php
$matches = array_filter($arr, function($el) {
  return $el['itag'] == 22;
});
print_r($matches);
// or
$key = key($matches);
?>
```

If 22 is a variable, you'll have to import/use it into the closure's scope:

```
...
$matches = array_filter($arr, function($el) use ($someVar) {
  return $el['itag'] == $someVar;
...
```

Comment: There is syntax error, and I dont understand $el function, you didnt call it or did you?

Comment: @BerkErarslan If you are using old (pre-5.3) PHP version, that would produce syntax error on anonymous functions. Time to upgrade :) Or take the function out as named function and give it's name to array_filter.